# Method clearLayers not clearing any markers

Tags: leaflet, requestanimationframe

I am attempting to add a custom option to the Leaflet plugin [MovingMarker](https://github.com/ewoken/Leaflet.MovingMarker/blob/master/MovingMarker.js) so that, if truthy, each marker is removed at the end of the respective animation. This plugin extends the [L.Marker](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker) class and employs the [window.requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) method to animate the markers.

With this in mind, I've added a `destroyedState: 4` line in the statics properties and a `remove: false` line in the options properties. I've also added the following code blocks:

*Getter*

```
isDestroyed: function() {
    return this._state === L.Marker.MovingMarker.destroyedState;
}
```

---

*Setter*

```
destroy: function() {
    if (this.isDestroyed()) {
        return;
    }
    this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.destroyedState;
    this._removeMarker();
},
```

---

```
onEnd: function(map) {
    L.Marker.prototype.onEnd.call(this, map);

    if (this.options.remove && (this.isDestroyed())) {
        this.destroy();
        return;
    }
    this._removeMarker();
},
```

---

```
 _removeMarker: function() {
    this._state = L.Marker.MovingMarker.destroyedState;
    if (this._animRequested) {
        L.Util.cancelAnimFrame(this._animId);
        this._animRequested = false;
    }
    this.L.Marker.MovingMarker.clearLayers(this, map);
    this.L.Marker.MovingMarker = null;
},
```

Unfortunately, for some reason the method [*clearLayers*](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) isn't doing the intended job when option remove is set to true. I've tried the method *removeLayer* at no avail either. I wonder what am I doing wrong? Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/o53njksy/229/) with the `remove` option set to true on line 232.